# Set SMTP envelope MAIL FROM using grails asynchronous mail plugin

Tags: email, grails

I'd like to set the SMTP envelope sender to a different value per message in some grails code, distinct from the message From: address, which I want to be the same for each email.
This is to do VERP-like bounce tracking.

I can't see a way to set this in an asynchronousMailService.sendMail call. Is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it stands there is a [pull request](https://github.com/gpc/grails-mail/pull/3) for the Grails mail plugin to add support for this. There is also a [blog post](http://www.pither.com/articles/2011/03/13/grails-mail-patch-for-envelopefrom-verp) which talks about this specific feature. If you need this feature you can always download the forked version of the plugin.